# Can a button toggle a 1-bit pin?

Tags: pins, button, logisim

I know that buttons, when pressed will send a value of one, but when released will go back to zero. So what I'm asking is can a button TOGGLE a one(or more) one bit pin(s)? I'm using Logisim, but I figured it would be essentially the same in real life.[image: What I want]

Above is an example of what I want.

Comment: "I know that buttons, when pressed will send a value of one, but when released will go back to zero." No, and that is a dangerous way to think about them.

Comment: A momentary switch is a transmission or conduction between pin 1&2. Never assume the connection of the other pin, unless specified or tested.  Pullup R with switch to ground is most common.   A momentary switch has memory to return to unpressed state but never for toggle function. This takes at least 2 internal  switches or internal latched memory states with 4  combinations of in & out

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez Abrams is there a non-dangerous way to think about them?

Comment: A (momentary, normally-open) button makes a connection when pressed, and breaks it when released. What "make" and "break" effect depends on the rest of the circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

There are mechanical switches that alternate on/off on successive pushes- the mechanism is similar to that in many ball-point pens.

You can use a momentary pulse to toggle a flip-flop, but typically with a mechanical switch you have to debounce the input because mechanical switches will often make and break a number of times after being operated before settling to their final state. Since logic can usually respond in nanoseconds, the flip-flop would toggle some unknown number of times during this (milliseconds long) process and end up in goodness-knows-what state at the end.

This debouncing can be done a number of different ways- in hardware, in firmware or some combination of the two. Usually it requires a clock or some RC timing mechanism but if you use a SPDT switch and cross-coupled gates to generate the clock for the flip-flop, the switch itself provides the timing.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is properly debounced a (surprise) toggle flip-flop could be used. It's basically a D-flip-flop with the inverted output fed back to the input.

The button would need to drive the clock input.

[image]